Product of low dimensional Hausdorff measures
Let $\mathcal{H}^n$ and $\mathcal{H}^m$ be Hausdorff measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$. We know that the product measure $\mathcal{H}^n\otimes \mathcal{H}^m$ is the Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^{n+m}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$. (Here $\otimes$ refers to the construction of product measures by first forming premeasures on measurable rectangles and restricting the induced outer measure on measuable sets).
Now for any $0\le s< n$ and $0\le r< m$, since $\mathcal{H}^s$ and $\mathcal{H}^r$ are no longer sigma-finite measures, the product $\mathcal{H}^s\otimes \mathcal{H}^r$ is not the only product measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ such that $\lambda(A\times B)=\mathcal{H}^s(A)\mathcal{H}^r(B)$. I want to ask

Is there any relationship between $\mathcal{H}^s\otimes \mathcal{H}^r$ and $\mathcal{H}^{s+r}$?
Though $\mathcal{H}^s$ is not sigmma-finite for $s<n$, it is semifinite in the sense that for any $A$ with $\mathcal{H}^s(A)=\infty$, there is $B\subset A$ such that $\mathcal{H}^s(B)<\infty$. Is $\mathcal{H}^s\otimes \mathcal{H}^r$ also semifinite?


Do we not have $\mathcal H^0\otimes\mathcal H^1([0,1]\times{0})=\infty$, seen as a subset of $\mathbb R^{1+1}$?

My apologies but I do not think it is... I was wrong, I think $\mathcal H^0\otimes\mathcal H^1([0,1]\times{0})$ should be zero. What is your definition of the product measure, since the factors are not $\sigma$-finite?

For any two measurable sets $A$ and $B$, the premeasure assigns $A\times B$ with $\mathcal{H}^s(A)\mathcal{H}^r(B)$, then this premeasure induces an outer measure which further induces a measure. In your example, $[0,1]\times{0}$ is a measurable rectangle so the measure is the product of $\mathcal{H}^0([0,1])\mathcal{H}^1({1})=\infty\cdot 0=0$. I will edit the question again.

I assume that your (outer) measure is defined as
$$ \mathcal H^s\otimes\mathcal H^r(S) := \inf\left\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathcal H^s(A_k)\mathcal H^r(B_k)\middle|A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)^{\mathbb N},B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^m)^{\mathbb N},S\subset\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty A_k\times B_k\right\}, $$
with the convention $\infty\times x=x\times\infty=\infty$ if $x\in(0,\infty]$, $0\times\infty=\infty\times0=0$.
Fix $0\leq s<r$. I will show that in codimension high enough (say $n=m\geq s+r$), there exists a set $X$ such that $\mathcal H^s\otimes\mathcal H^r(X)<\infty$ but $\mathcal H^{s+r}(X)=\infty$, and a set $Y$ with the reverse property. In fact if $s>0$ then we can choose the measure to be zero rather than just finite. Obviously this shows the measures are not dominated one by the other, even up to constants. Moreover, in codimension high enough, the product is not semifinite.
The product measure is small. For any $0<\alpha\leq n$, there exists a compact set $K_\alpha\subset\mathbb R^n$ such that $\mathcal H^\alpha(K_\alpha)=1$. Then, in one direction, whenever $n\geq s+r$,
$$ \mathcal H^s\otimes\mathcal H^r((\mathbb Z^n+K_{s+r})\times\{0\})\leq\mathcal H^s(\mathbb Z^n+K_{s+r+\varepsilon})\times\mathcal H^r(\{0\})=0 $$
and $\mathcal H^{s+r}((\mathbb Z^n+K_{s+r})\times\{0\})=\infty$, so the property holds for $X=K_{s+r}$.
The measure is not semifinite. I will consider subsets of the diagonal; namely, for $S\subset\mathbb R^n$ I write $\Delta(S)$ for the set of pairs $(x,x)\in\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n$ where $x$ ranges over $S$. Let $S$ be a set whose product measure is finite:
$$ \mathcal H^s\otimes\mathcal H^r(\Delta(S))<\infty. $$
Let $(A,B)$ be a cover as above whose associated sum if finite. Let $I$ and $J$ be the subsets of $k\in\mathbb N$ such that, respectively, $\mathcal H^s(A_k)$ is finite or infinite. Then the set
$$ U:=\bigcup_{k\in J}B_k $$
has zero measure for $\mathcal H^r$, and the same holds for
$$ V:=\bigcup_{k\in I}A_k, $$
since $\mathcal H^s(A_k)<\infty$ imposes $\mathcal H^r(A_k)=0$, and the union is countable. But then $S\subset U\cup V$ must have zero measure for $\mathcal H^r$. Since clearly $\Delta(S)\subset S\times S$, we also see that $\Delta(S)$ has zero product measure when $\mathcal H^r(S)=0$. Putting everything together, we see that $\Delta(S)$ has product measure either zero or infinite, depending on whether $\mathcal H^r(S)$ is zero or positive. In particular, there cannot be a subset of $\Delta([0,1]^n)$ with positive but finite product measure.
The product measure is large. Consider $\Delta(K_r)$; since $\mathcal H^r(K_r)>0$, it has infinite product measure. However, if $s>0$, $\mathcal H^{s+r}(\Delta(K_r))=0$, and in any case $\mathcal H^{s+r}(\Delta(K_r))<\infty$. This means we have the result for $Y=\Delta(K_r)$. Note that if $s=0$, then for any $Y$ with $\mathcal H^{s+r}(Y)=0$, the projection $Z$ of $Y$ in $\mathbb R^m$ must also have $\mathcal H^r(Z)=0$ (because the projection is a contraction), and
$$ \mathcal H^s\otimes\mathcal H^r(Y)\leq\mathcal H^s(\mathbb R^n)\mathcal H^r(Z)=0, $$
so we cannot find a most extreme example where the product measure is infinite but the Hausdorff measure is zero.
